# How do I call an onChange function for foundation Orbit Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have a foundation orbit slider. I am trying to call a function when the orbit image changes. In the jquery below the ready.fndtn.orbit works. However the after-slide-change will not fire. Foundations docs offer no help for this issue.Any suggestions or help is very welcome

```
<ul id="featured1" class="no-bullet example-orbit" data-orbit data-options="animation:fade;
    timer: false;
    slide_number: false;
      pause_on_hover:false;
      animation_speed:800;
      navigation_arrows:true;
      bullets:false;">

    <li id="slideImg1">
        <a href="training/hygiene.cfm"><img src="img/slide5.png" alt="stuff here"></a>
    </li>

    <li id="slideImg2">
        <a href=""><img src="img/slide6.png" alt="See a Demo of the CIS-CAT Assesment Tool" ></a>
    </li>
    <li id="slideImg3">
        <a href=""><img src="img/slide7.png" alt="The Critical SecurityControls are now available in Japanese"></a>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
    $(document).on('ready.fndtn.orbit', function(e) {
            captionFunction();
        });
        $(document).on('after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit', function(e) {
            captionFunction();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the Foundation docs, it looks like you'll want to select the `ul` element to add the event handler, in your case: `$("#featured1").on("after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit")....` rather than selecting `$(document)`. I tried it on a quick sample and the events fired just fine.

See http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html and search for 'after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit' to see the example I was looking at.

### Update

I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neuronaut/jon1vd25/6/) that demonstrates this working (you'll have to scroll to the bottom in the javascript panel to see the pertinent stuff). It seems the key is to surround the javascript with `$(document).ready(function(){` and `});`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // this should come before initializing orbit or it won't fire
    $("#featured1").on('ready.fndtn.orbit', function(e) {
        console.log('orbit is ready');
    });

    $(document).foundation({
       orbit: {
            animation: 'fade',
            timer: false,
            slide_number: false,
            pause_on_hover: false,
            animation_speed: 800,
            navigation_arrows: true,
            bullets: false
        }
    });

    $("#featured1").on('after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit', function(e) {
        console.log('getting after slide change event!');
    });
});
```

Note that I had to add the call to `$(document).foundation` and I had to set the timer to true because I couldn't see the navigation arrows to change slides manually. Lastly, I don't have your images so it's pretty ugly, but I think it demonstrates how to get things working well enough even so ;)

Anyway, when you visit that link, open your browser's javascript console to see the output "getting after slide change event!".

Comment: i have tried that code. It does not fire for me. Im using foundation 5. Are you using an earlier version?

Comment: @ConnerHasbrouck My test was simple: I just used the slider already present on that documentation page by entering this in the javascript console: `$(".orbit-slides-container").on("after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit", function(event, orbit) { console.info("after slide change"); });` and then I clicked through the slides and checked that "after slide change" was printed to the console each time. I believe those docs are for foundation 5.

Comment: @ConnerHasbrouck I've updated my answer with what I think will be a solution for you.

Comment: neither the ready or after-slide-click fire in my code. only when i use document.on(ready.....) does it fire. I dont have the class orbit-slides-container on my orbit slider like the example. would that cause this not to fire?

Comment: @ConnerHasbrouck I'm not using `orbit-slides-container` in my jsFiddle example and it's working there, so that won't be a problem. In fact, to create the fiddle I just copied/pasted your code exactly. The only change (other than the javascript changes shown in my answer above) was that I set `timer:true` which I only did because I couldn't see the navigation arrows. Click that jsFiddle link above to see what I did there.

Comment: i  tried your code and its still not firing. no clue what it could be. Either way thank you for the help